# How to enable the input in checkbox if i check the checkbox? cuz it always disable when i check the checkbox with input type

Tags: javascript, html

How to enable the input in checkbox if i check the checkbox?

It always disable when I check the checkbox with input type.

```js
function ckChange(ckType) {
  var ckName = document.getElementsByName(ckType.name);
  var checked = document.getElementById(ckType.id);

  if (checked.checked) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ckName.length; i++) {

      if (!ckName[i].checked) {
        ckName[i].disabled = true;
      } else {
        ckName[i].disabled = false;
      }
    }
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < ckName.length; i++) {
      ckName[i].disabled = false;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" placeholder="toBeReturn" name="progress" id="progress1" value="1" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange(this)"> For use in showroom to be return on
<input type="date" name="progress" id="progress3" placeholder="date">
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" placeholder="OnLoan" name="progress" id="progress2" value="1" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange(this)"> On Loan
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" placeholder="Other" name="progress" id="progress6" value="1" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange(this)"> Other
<input type="text" name="progress" id="progress3" placeholder="State the Purpose">
```

I need help to complete my project thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simply switch around what you have in the "if" and "else" statement so that the opposite happens.

Also, if you're loading the page with the checkbox unchecked, also add "disabled" to the text input so it matches.

```js
function ckChange(ckType) {
  var ckName = document.getElementsByName(ckType.name);
  var checked = document.getElementById(ckType.id);

  if (checked.checked) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ckName.length; i++) {
      ckName[i].disabled = false;
    }
  } else {

    for (var i = 0; i < ckName.length; i++) {
      if (!ckName[i].checked) {
        ckName[i].disabled = true;
      } else {
        ckName[i].disabled = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<th>
  <input type="checkbox" placeholder="toBeReturn" name="progress" id="progress3" value="1" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange(this)"> For use in showroom to be return on <input type="date" name="progress" id="progress3" placeholder="date" disabled>
</th>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your 'for' statement, the 'for' statement matched all the check-boxs including the one you checked which you need exclude from then, so you may try it like this:

```
function ckChange(ckType) {
        var ckName = document.getElementsByName(ckType.name);
        var checked = document.getElementById(ckType.id);

        if (checked.checked) {
            for (var i = 0; i < ckName.length; i++) {
                if(ckName[id].id !==checked.id){
                    ckName[i].disabled = false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < ckName.length; i++) {
                if(ckName[id].id !==checked.id){
                    if (!ckName[i].checked) {
                    ckName[i].disabled = true;
                    } else {
                        ckName[i].disabled = false;
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```